# What scope to use for launching a task in Kotlin from a controller?

Tags: kotlin, spring-mvc, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

My Kotlin App is using Spring to expose an API that should execute a long task in the background. We need to return

```
@PutMapping("/refresh")
fun refresh() = {
    GlobalScope.launch(IO) { refreshDataFromCache() }
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body("""{"result": "accepted"}""")
}
```

IntelliJ complains that using the GlobalScope is an anti-pattern. However, I cannot just add *suspend* to the controller function or it won't work. Neither I can use *runBlocking* or the method will need to wait until finishing producing a REST timeout

What should I add as the scope of this function to use [structured concurrency](https://elizarov.medium.com/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952)?

Comment: Why you can't add `suspend` modifier? Do you need to launch and forget `refreshDataFromCache()` without waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Yes, I want the method to return immediately.  Waiting to this long operation would result in a gateway timeout due to the API gateway limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to inject some scope other than GlobalScope into your resource. If your framework already provides some sort of "application scope" that will be cancelled when your application shuts down, that seems appropriate.

Failing that -- a coroutine scope is just a wrapper around a Job (well, and other coroutine context items). So you can create a new Job during app startup, and simply `CoroutineScope(job)` to make your application coroutine scope. Then just do `job.cancel()` during app shutdown and that will ensure any coroutines launched in that scope will be cancelled.

Edited to add my solution:

```
private val jobScope = CoroutineScope(IO)

@PutMapping("/refresh")
fun refresh() = {
    jobScope.launch(IO) { refreshDataFromCache() }
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body("""{"result": "accepted"}""")
}

@PreDestroy
fun stopTasks() {
    jobScope.cancel("Closing app")
}
```

Comment: I had added my implementation according to the description. Feel free to update and comment

Comment: I see, that's even simpler, great

Answer (score 1):

To leverage structured concurrency, as described [here in the **Parallel decomposition** section](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow), you can use `coroutineScope` function:

```
@PutMapping("/refresh")
suspend fun refresh() = coroutineScope {
    async { refreshDataFromCache() } // this will run in parallel
    ResponseEntity.accepted().body("""{"result": "accepted"}""")
}
```

`refresh()` should be marked as `suspend` to use `coroutineScope`.

Comment: But then the refresh method is  marked as suspend.

Comment: why you can't add `suspend`? If I'm not mistaken, according to the docs, it is not prohibited.

Comment: At least it fails in my test. I even had to add Reactor dependencies the client is not expecting it to be reactive or at least it returns empty values

Comment: Thanks, man! Your answer is what I was looking for for a long time. You are a genius!